# timyMCE allowed tags in django

Tags: django, tinymce, bleach

In django I am using tinyMCE field for admin. I need to add a set of tags allowed by me, how can I do this?

```
'paste_as_text': True,
```

not suitable, need to write a list and make it universally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE has a `valid_elements` configuration option that allows you to state exactly what tags are allowed:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements

There are some other configuration options that you may want to look at as well:

- `valid_children`: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_children
- `extended_valid_elements`: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements

Comment: Can i use this for django settings.py?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anything about Django or how it is configured so I cannot tell you how you would implement these specific TinyMCE configuration settings in that environment.